# Upstart stop if running

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, upstart

I have a Jenkins job to stop a node application, deploy code, and start the application.

The start/stop is done with an Upstart script.

I use `initctl stop node-App`

If the job is running, this works great.  But if the app has died or is in a stopped state, the output is `initctl: Unknown instance:`

This causes the Jenkins job to fail and not proceed to the next steps.

Is there a way to check if the job is started before issuing the start command?  Or is there a way for Jenkins to not consider that an error and fail the job?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A colleague came up with a great solution

```
if ( initctl status node-App | grep start ); then
  initctl stop node-App
fi
```

Very simple and works properly when run from Jenkins

Comment: I simpler syntax would be `status node-App | grep start && stop node-App`

Comment: @unnu: your one-liner would leave the return code as non-zero.  I believe this might still cause Jenkins to fail. The above solution is better since it will set the return code to zero.

Comment: @jwfearn The one-liner returns 0 if the job was shutdown and returns 1 if it was not running. Considering the question your answer is right ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using similar construction

```
initctl stop node-App || echo "node-App was not running"
```